# Replace element on filtered array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have this array in Typescript:

```
[ 
  { "size": "100.34 KB", "name": "Phone.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "object" }, 
  { "size": "606.34 KB", "name": "Tulips.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "flower" }, 
  { "size": "500.00 KB", "name": "Penguins.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "animal" }, ... 
]
```

You can only have 1 element of each type in this array, i.e., the array will never have two types of "animal".

I want to replace Tulips.jpg by a new element (Cactus.jpg), keeping the other elements, like this:

```
[ 
  { "size": "100.34 KB", "name": "Phone.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "object" }, 
  { "size": "900.00 KB", "name": "Cactus.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "flower" }, 
  { "size": "500.00 KB", "name": "Penguins.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "animal" }, ... 
]
```

So I tried to filter this array and take only the flower and replace this element, like this:

```
array.filter(item => item.type === "flower")
     .splice(0, array.length, newElement);
```

This is not working, my array still the same. How can I do that?

```js
let newElement = {
    "size": "900.00 KB",
    "name": "Cactus.jpg",
    "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg",
    "type": "flower"
  }

  let array = [ 
  { "size": "100.34 KB", "name": "Phone.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "object" }, 
  { "size": "606.34 KB", "name": "Tulips.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "flower" }, 
  { "size": "500.00 KB", "name": "Penguins.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "animal" }
]
console.log(array
  .filter(item => item.type === "flower")
  .splice(0, array.length, newElement)
)
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question and I deleted by mistake

Comment: I added it with the new element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find index of element returned by `filter` then splice one element at that index, replacing it

```js
const newElement = { "size": "900.00 KB", "name": "Cactus.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "flower" }; 
let array = [ 
  { "size": "100.34 KB", "name": "Phone.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "object" }, 
  { "size": "606.34 KB", "name": "Tulips.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "flower" }, 
  { "size": "500.00 KB", "name": "Penguins.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "animal" }  
];

let newarray = array.filter(item => item.type === "flower")
var index = array.indexOf(newarray[0])
array.splice(index, 1, newElement);
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method creates a new array which is the one you're using `splice()` on, while the original remains unchanged. Try

```js
 const newElement = { "size": "900.00 KB", "name": "Cactus.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "flower" }; 
let array = [ 
  { "size": "100.34 KB", "name": "Phone.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "object" }, 
  { "size": "606.34 KB", "name": "Tulips.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "flower" }, 
  { "size": "500.00 KB", "name": "Penguins.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "animal" }  
];

array = array.filter(item => item.type === "flower")
  .splice(0, array.length, newElement);
  
console.log(array);
```

Comment: But the original array has items of other types, such as "animals". If I filter the array and assign it to itself, won't they disappear?

Comment: Yes. You said "This is not working, my array still the same." so I assumed that's what you wanted.

Comment: No..."I want to replace Tulips.jpg by a new element (Cactus.jpg)", i.e. the other elements should still.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a Map instead of an Array

```
// create map out of array
const optionsByType = [{ type: 'flower'}, [{ type: 'animal'}]].reduce((map, opt) => {
 map.set(opt.type, opt);
 return map;
}, new Map());

// overrides the flower key
optionsByType.set('flower', { type: 'flower', "name": "Cactus.jpg" })
```

Comment: Can you show a snippet with OP's array any newElement?

Answer (score 0):

**.filter** method will filter the array acc to the condition and will return a new array, new array will not have filtered out elements.

you can use **`.map`** method and change the property of matched element and return the element.

```js
arr = [  
     { "size": "606.34 KB", "name": "Tulips.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "flower" }, 
     { "size": "500.00 KB", "name": "Penguins.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "animal" } 
];

let newItem = { "size": "900.00 KB", "name": "Cactus.jpg", "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg", "type": "flower" }

arr = arr.map((ele) => {if(ele.type == newItem.type){ return newItem } return ele});

console.log(arr);
/*
[
  {
    "size": "900.00 KB",
    "name": "Cactus.jpg",
    "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg",
    "type": "flower"
  },
  {
    "size": "500.00 KB",
    "name": "Penguins.jpg",
    "documentoContentType": "image/jpeg",
    "type": "animal"
  }
]

*/
```

Comment: Its is clear that I dont want to change de name of the item, but the item itself

Comment: This is returning an empty array

Comment: @aseolin I'm sorry, did you run the code snippet that I have in my ans, It does not return empty array but the result array with a replaced element. I have also shown the returned value in an comment.